# Is there a way to highlight square brackets/citations in RMarkdown's Source mode?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

It works perfectly fine for me in Visual Mode (citations highlighted in blue), but I would also like to have my citations highlighted while writing the manuscript in the Source Mode. Is there a way to do it?
Cheers